Does video_player in flutter supports H264 Format?
I want to use flutter video_player, it plays videos in emulator, but not able to play H.264 mp4 videos in most of real android device, anyone know the solution?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:newflutter/views/authscreens/login.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class LocalVideoStoryItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoPath;
  final Duration duration;
  final Widget? caption;

  const LocalVideoStoryItem({
    required this.videoPath,
    required this.duration,
    this.caption,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LocalVideoStoryItemState createState() => _LocalVideoStoryItemState();
}

class _LocalVideoStoryItemState extends State<LocalVideoStoryItem> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  GetStorage localMemory = GetStorage();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.videoPath);
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _controller.play();
      });
    });
    _controller.setLooping(true);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
        if (widget.caption != null)
          Positioned(
            bottom: 10,
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            child: widget.caption!,
          ),
        if (widget.caption == null)
          Positioned(
            bottom: 10,
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Explore ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      color: Color(0xFF10489B),
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff00BAE4),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Get.offAll(() => const Login());
                        localMemory.write('showSplashScreen', false);
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Get Started',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18),
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Its playing all videos in emulator but not local or url mp4 videos, play a local mp4 videos in flutter. If anyone knows, kindly provide the solution or any type of other depedency
